# EF5: Attach multiple results from stored proc to context

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have a stored proc in Entity Framework 5, returning multiple result sets of entities.
Attaching each entity to the context is very slow.
Is there a better / faster / easier way to do this?

```
    using (var context = new MyEntities())
    {                
        var resultSet1 = context.ExecMyStoredProc();
        foreach (var a in resultSet1) context.ASet.Attach(a);
        var resultSet2 = resultSet1.GetNextResult<B>();
        foreach (var b in resultSet2) context.BSet.Attach(b);
        var resultSet3 = resultSet2.GetNextResult<C>();
        foreach (var c in resultSet3) context.CSet.Attach(c);
        .                
        .
    }
```

Comment: How many results do you have? Also, do you need to attach the results at all? As far as I understand entities returned from stored procedures are automatically being tracked as AppendOnly

Comment: @Pawel I have a total of 17 result sets returned from the stored procedure.

Comment: How many entities in each of the result set (or total)?

Comment: @Pawel between 10 - 100 entities. I did a test and the entities are indeed tracked, so I don't have to attach them. Problem solved! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to attach the results at all? As far as I understand entities returned from stored procedures are automatically being tracked as AppendOnly.